# mac os find command no terminating character

Tags: shell, unix

In my git project I need to remove all files ending with **.pyc. I therefore run the below command, but got this error of `no terminating ";"` that I do not understand what it means.

```
find . -name "**.pyc" -exec git rm {};
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

If I just run `find . -name "**.pyc"` I get a list of all files of format .pyc.

Comment: If you have a decent shell: `git rm **/*.pyc`

Comment: You need to finish the exec command with `\;` or `+`; read the `find` manpage to see the difference (individual calls vs a single call with multiple args of the specified command)

Comment: I got it now. Thanks the command git rm "**/*.pyc" removed all the files. Will you post it as an answer so this can be closed?

Comment: As it stands, you're asking about the `find` command (which is not a Git command at all). I switched the tags around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute `find . -name "**.pyc" -exec git rm {};`, the shell reads the `;` as a terminating character and executes the command `find . -name "**.pyc" -exec git rm {}`.  But this is an error, because `find` expects the `-exec` command to be terminated by a `;`. That is, you need to pass `;` as one of the arguments to `find`.  You accomplish that by escaping it to the shell, either with `find . -name "**.pyc" -exec git rm {} \;` or `find . -name "**.pyc" -exec git rm {} ";"`   Another option is to terminate the `-exec` with `+`, which will invoke `git rm` with more than one argument, resulting in fewer invocations of `git`.  This is slightly more convenient, since `+` does not need to be escaped.